# Pandas to_html does not show the appended data

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to export my pandas DataFrame to a html page, through the to_html() functionality, the output html page does not show the appended data-rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TEST1', 'TEST2'])
df_test.append({'TEST1':11, 'TEST2':22}, ignore_index=True)
df_test.append({'TEST1':33, 'TEST2':44}, ignore_index=True)
return df_test.to_html()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pandas [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) not working inplace is necessary assign output back:

```
df_test = df_test.append({'TEST1':11, 'TEST2':22}, ignore_index=True)
df_test = df_test.append({'TEST1':33, 'TEST2':44}, ignore_index=True)
```